# InkAnalyzer throws FileNotFoundException on Vista deployment

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-vista

I have a WPF C# application that makes use of the InkAnalyzer class. On my development platform (Windows XP), I have added references to IACore.dll and IAWinFx.dll for the project before building the release.

However, when I tried to run this on a HP TouchSmart tablet PC (on Windows Vista), the application throws a "FileNotFoundException". Offending file name is IACore.dll.

Next, I selected the "Copy Local" option for both files, and rebuilt the application. However, once that is done, yet another file is not found. This time it is "IALoader.dll".

I realise that I must be missing something on the HP TouchSmart (on Windows Vista). Is the Vista laptop missing a SDK?

---

## A Solution

I couldn't find IACore.msm anywhere on my SDK, and it's a recent SDK (XP Tablet PC SDK version 1.7), so I used Search to find the IALoader.dll, and manually copied it to my application's folder. No more complaints after that.

However, if there's a way for me to avoid bloating my application deployment with these files, it would be great. Thanks for your help, Jared!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like this problem was encountered by a few other people as well.  The basic problem is that the assembly is not installed in the GAC but in the Windows SDK directory.  In order for your application to ensure it's loaded it must include the IACore.msm in the setup project or manually install the framework.

Full Thread:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/719cbbde-013e-4165-b694-6a994d833352/